# Quad trees pertaining to 2d collision

Tags: javascript, 2d, prototype, collision, quadtree

I've been studying this:

https://github.com/mikechambers/ExamplesByMesh/blob/master/JavaScript/QuadTree/src/QuadTree.js

and I believe I understand the general idea about quad trees, although I do have two questions about how they work, and the implementation above:

1. Wouldnt you have to rebuild the entire tree every several ms? In Javascript wouldnt this be extremely slow to do?
2. If I have something like this: http://davzy.com/screenshots/skitched-20120318-180324.png, then its easy enough to find the other dots in the same quad but I have a rectangle that hits 3 different quads, is there a way I can make it display as a child of all 3 of those quads?
3. On 144 of the above example it says this Node.prototype._classConstructor = Node;, I'm just curious what's going on. I thought prototype was a way to define a function or variable for future use within a class, so I'm not sure what this line does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Wouldnt you have to rebuild the entire tree every several ms? In Javascript wouldnt this be extremely slow to do?

I suppose that depends on what you're using it for; but yes, the author's collision-detection example in [his blog post about his QuadTree implementation](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/03/21/javascript-quadtree-implementation/) will clear the tree and repopulate it roughly 24 times per second (so, about once per 40 ms). You can judge for yourself whether that's "extremely slow"; on my machine it looks quite smooth. (And even if not, I would expect the rebuilding of the QuadTree to actually be cheaper/faster than the redrawing of all of the circles on the canvas.)

> 2. […] I have a rectangle that hits 3 different quads, is there a way I can make it display as a child of all 3 of those quads?

I'm not sure what you mean by "display", but: if you call the constructor with the `pointQuad` parameter set to `false`, then items are two-dimensional (i.e., they have `width` and `height` in addition to `x` and `y`), and every item will be a child of the smallest quad that it fits completely inside. In your example, since the rectangle crosses the vertical midline of the canvas, it will be a direct child of the root quad.

> 3. On 144 of the above example it says this Node.prototype._classConstructor = Node;, I'm just curious what's going on. […]

The `Node` "class" has a "subclass" named `BoundsNode` (used when the items are two-dimensional), and `BoundsNode.prototype._classConstructor` is set to `BoundsNode` (which overrides the inherited `Node.prototype._classConstructor`). This allows `Node`'s `subdivide` method to write `new this._classConstructor(...)` in order to construct a new `BoundsNode` if `this` is a `BoundsNode`, and a new plain `Node` if `this` is a plain `Node`.